# Special characters in slug (in All-in-One Calendar - WordPress) result in error 404

Tags: php, wordpress

In my site I use the All-in-One Calendar plugin by Then.ly. It shows events from external iCal-feeds. Everything works fine, except for one thing: if the title of an event ends with special characters (e.g. stars), clicking on the Read more button ('Lees meer') results in a 404 error. If I manually remove the stars from the end of the slug, everything works fine.

Example: view on [July 25](http://www.luchtspin.nl/kalender): *GWOEMUL / THE HOST ★★★★*. Click on it to expand and next click on the 'Lees meer' button. (The slug for this event is "../gwoemul-the-host-★★★★/..")

My question: how do I automatically remove special characters (or make them work!) from the **slugs** that contain them?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested: I was able to fix the issue with the help of another plugin called [Strings Sanitizer](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/strings-sanitizer).